# How do I break up a line of code into several rows without breaking it into new lines in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Example:

```
// TODO: @blocked - Search function blocked until backend implements 
// string to ID conversion. 
// Without it the client must know the id of a store/country/region 
// which is not feasible.
```

Only the first line will register as a **TODO** and the following will be registered as normal comments.

Is there a way to continue a line of code on the next row without breaking it?

Comment: You would have to change the TODO regex which is accessible from settings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066879/is-it-possible-to-use-multiline-todos-in-intellij-idea-13