# How can I get Intellij Idea to recognise todo comments on multiple lines in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I would like Intellij Idea to recognise all the lines of the following as a todo item

```
//todo: some long description
//  that spans multiple lines
```

The first line is recognised by Intellij Idea as a todo item but the second line is not recognised.

This seems to suggest it is possible if the second line is indented and follows directly on from the `todo` tag.

[Is it possible to use multiline todo's in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066879/is-it-possible-to-use-multiline-todos-in-intellij-idea)

but when programming in Dart, the second line is not recognised.

I've tried tabs and double spaces.

It works with the `*/ comment */` style but not the double backslash `//comment` style

Comment: Actually I just stumbled on this - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34694/Dart-Multiline-TODOs